# Maven - copying properties file from SVN to Linux based App Server machines

Tags: linux, maven

We are using Maven and Jenkins for our automated Build and Deployment needs. Our Build Engineer has left and it is now up to me (Java Architect) to implement a few remaining stuff. I tried a lot of things to resolve this issue we are having. The problem statement is -

We have made a separate project in Eclipse to store properties files. The Developers check-in the properties file into SVN once they make any changes to it. Now we want that Maven, when triggered to do a deploy, to do the following - 
1. Take the latest properties files from the SVN from the project used to store properties files. 
2. Copy the same onto the Linux based JBoss App Server's /conf/ folder
3. Carry on with its deployment task.

We would like to have solution to point 1 and 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the exact answer. But it is quite doable. Quick google search did not show up any svn related plugin to retrieve properties. But you can always write your own maven plugin to do that task. For an example, if you want to retrieve properties file from a svn location to a local file system, just write a simple maven plugin[1] using the svn-kit [2].

we can use maven-wagon plugin[3] to transfer any artifact to a destination. Given that it supports SCP i would go with that. (just like a doing a scp to a remote Linux machine)

HTH.

[1] http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

[2] http://svnkit.com/

[3] http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html